# Looking for an open source CMS with excellent internationalization and localization

Tags: php, ruby, localization, content-management-system, internationalization

Can anyone suggest a CMS able to offer the following features:

- Free/open source
- Support for multiple languages (both frontend and backend)
- Support for translating content (i.e. an article can have 1+ translations)
- Support for different content types, namely pages, articles (timestamped, with comments) and image (galleries).
- Support for basic categorization (just a level of sections is sufficient)
- Support for media management (localizable image galleries)
- User friendly
- lightweight and fast
- PHP or Ruby based
- mature enough

Personally, I can only think of Drupal 6, but it's quite an overkill for what I want to do, and localization is not working 100%. I basically can live with anything which was built *from the ground up* with localization in mind.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this question at superuser.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of looking around and tryng out various demo site, [SPIP](http://www.spip.net) seems to be the only proper solution to my problem. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

[Daisy](http://www.daisycms.org/daisy/index.html) was built from the ground-up with [localization](http://www.daisycms.org/daisydocs-2_3/537-cd/557-cd.html) in mind.

In Daisy, each document can have one or more language *variants*, and Daisy tracks whether the source document and the translated variant are in-sync or not. This makes it very easy to manage change.

For example, I can ask Daisy 'Give me a list of documents for which either the Japanese translation doesn't exist, or it is not longer in sync with the original'. You can do this for any file type, including screenshots.

I think it hits all of your requirements except that it's built on the Java stack.

Comment: Interesting, however:

- It's build on the Java Stack...
- It doesn't seem to offer multiple backend languages...

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that would be a dealbreaker. If anything, seeing how Daisy handles languages can help you evaluate other platforms. Good luck in your search.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`Joomla`](http://www.joomla.org/)?  I'm not sure if it fulfills all your requirements, but it's a suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: By personal experience, I'm not too fond of Mambo derivatives. I used Mambo in the past and wasn't too happy about it: I'd prefer something more lightweight, if possible.

Anyhow, that's a suggestion alright... I suppose I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: I've found Joomla to require so much learning most projects would be better off just teaching the website maintainers a little HTML instead. If your project is large enough to justify hiring a Joomla specialist, sure, but otherwise be prepared to waste a lot of time learning how to create and maintain a Joomla website.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that.  Though if you know what you're doing the end result can be pretty good.  I've seen some pretty great Joomla sites.

Answer (score 0):

Probably under-kill, but WordPress with the qTranslate plugin works well for i18n of the admin interface plus the main content block of your page.